# How to mask ipaddress/hostname and port number from a web url?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a nodejs server running on my ec2 instance. I currently use the public hostname along with the port number(3000) to access my webpage? How do I mask this url with a more simple domain like example.com

My current url is something like this

> http://ec2-host-name:3000/

Answer (score 3):

1. Buy a domain name
2. Create a DNS record for your domain name that points to the EC2 server's IP address
3. Start hosting your app on port 80, the default HTTP port, so that you don't have to specify the port in the URL anymore

Comment: I have a domain name and yes I can use iptable rules to direct traffic on 80 to 3000. My server doesn't have a public ip, I access it on port 3000 using the public DNS provided by amazon eg: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com. Can I use route 53 to mask this url?

Comment: Can I use route 53 to create a DNS record?

Comment: Those XX values in the servers public DNS correspond to the public IP. You'll need to use the IP address for a root domain record. Ideally you would assign an Elastic IP to the server so that you don't ever have to worry about the IP changing. And yes you can create a DNS record with Route53, that's Route53's main function.